# Compile C Programs from Windows Powershell with MSVC

Tags: c, windows, powershell, visual-c++, compilation

Edit: To anyone interested in doing this, take a look at my answer below. I got this working exactly as I was hoping to.

I know this is a topic that has probably been addressed before, but I can't seem to find a straight answer in the searching I've done, everything is extremely convoluted.

I'm trying to get my Powershell set up so I can compile simple C programs directly from a Powershell terminal, and not need to use Visual Studio or the "developer console" they keep recommending.

So far I have installed the Visual Studio build tools, as I was trying to avoid downloading the entire Visual Studio IDE. I was able to compile a Hello World C program using the developer console as a test to make sure everything was working and it compiled and ran fine. However I want to be able to run cl.exe directly from Powershell without using the developer console.

I managed to add a folder to the environment variables in Windows System properties, and successfully got Powershell to recognize the cl command and show me this:

```
usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

I feel like I'm so close here, but when I actually try to run "cl hello.c" to compile my little test program I get this error:

```
hello.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set
```

I added the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x64" to the environment variables path section, but I noticed there are multiple cl.exe files in different folders.

Can anyone tell me how to dial this thing in so I can actually have the cl function fully functioning from Powershell? Thanks in advance for any help on this.

P.S.
I have WSL installed and have multiple Raspberry Pis that I could use the gcc compiler, but that is not my aim here.  I'm also aware of things like MinGW and Cygwin but am not looking to use those solutions. I am trying to get this specific scenario to work: using the cl command in Powershell without the developer console. It can't be THAT hard, and I feel like I'm so close and just need to add a few more Environment variables or something.

Here's a screenshot of me trying the cl command in PowerShell and the error it gives.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu62f.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured this out thanks to Chuck Walbourn, please check out his answer to see where I got all the appropriate directories to make this work. To add the environment variables permanently to your system so that typing "cl" from any PowerShell terminal will work, do the following for Windows 10 with the 2019 version of Visual Studio Build Tools (this will likely work with other variations but you will have to adjust things accordingly):

Hit Window Key and start typing "Environment Variables". You will see an option to "Edit the system environment variables". Click the "Environment Variables..." button in the bottom right of the Advanced Tab. You will see sections for "User variable names for " and "System variables". This next step assumes you don't see variables for "Include" and "Lib" in this section. Under the System variables section, hit "New..." and name the variable Include, and for the variable value, enter:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt
```

Make sure to check these folders actually exist on your system, and adjust version numbers and "Enterprise" accordingly. I had to change "Enterprise" to "BuildTools".

Next make a new variable called "Lib" and enter the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86
```

Same rule applies, make sure to adjust these directories to match your Visual Studio install directories.

Finally, assuming the Path variable already exists which it did for me, double click "Path" and add the following keys one by one by hitting the New button in the Path menu that pops up:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
```

Tweak the directories to match your system, and if necessary the x86 vs x64 directories (I just used x86).

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrmU0.jpg) highlighting some of the relevant windows and buttons mentioned in this post. Hopefully anyone messing with this stuff can figure out the minor details. Do all of this at your own risk, I have no idea if this could somehow hose your system if something gets screwed up.

If all goes well, you should be able to open PowerShell in the directory of your .c file, and type:

```
cl filename.c
```

And the system will output filename.obj and filename.exe

Success! Thanks again to Chuck for all the help, and thank you to thurizas for contributing and offering another potential solution.

Answer (score 2):

Open up a *Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt*. Assuming it has defaulted to your %VSINSTALLDIR% as normal, then search for `vcvars.bat` in that tree.

If you look in that file, you'll see that you need to set `INCLUDE`, `LIB`, and `PATH` to get command-line builds to work.

In particular, the "C" portion of the C/C++ Runtime is actually in the Windows 10 SDK under:

- `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\ucrt` for the headers
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\ucrt\<arch>` for the libraries.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrade-your-code-to-the-universal-crt).

Because Visual Studio supports many side-by-side toolsets, the compiler and the VC Runtime and "C++" portion of the include/libs are located under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<VSEdition>\VC\Tools\MSVC\<toolset>` in the `bin`, `include`, and `lib/<arch>` folders which should be set as part of the environment variables above.

For VS 2017 (15.9) Enterprise edition using the Windows 10 SDK (17763) for example, that would be:

MS-DOS Command Prompt syntax:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt
```

The Powershell syntax is:

```
$env:INCLUDE = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt'
```

Assuming you are creating a 32-bit (x86) program:

MS-DOS Command Prompt:

```
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86;
```

PowerShell:

```
$env:LIB = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86;'
```

> This should be sufficient for classic Win32 desktop development. For C++/CX, Managed C++, and/or UWP development you would need additional directories and the `LIBPATH` variable set.

And you want the compiler itself to be a 32-bit (x86) EXE:

MS-DOS Command Prompt:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;
%PATH%
```

PowerShell:

```
$env:PATH='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;' + $env:PATH
```

**VS 2019 16.11.3 w/ Windows SDK (19041)**

```
$env:INCLUDE = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt'
```

```
$env:LIB = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86;'
```

```
$env:PATH='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;' + $env:PATH
```

> Change `Enterprise` to the appropriate SKU: `Community`, `Professional`, `Enterprise`, or `BuildTools`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I tried adding both of those directories to the environment variables path section but I still get the same error. Is there some writeup or something on how to set INCLUDE and LIB like you mentioned? I'm not sure if I'm oversimplifying this process but I feel like I'm close and just need to make a few adjustments somewhere.

I also opened the vcvars.bat file but it is quite long and I'm not sure what to look for in there that would be useful to me to finish setting this up.

Comment: There is a [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line) page, but it mostly tells you to run those batch files.

Comment: Thanks again for all the additional info, I appreciate the help. I added all these directories to environment variables and I still get that pesky error when I try to compile. Would you be able to look at this screenshot and tell me if there is anything blatantly wrong or missing here?

https://imgur.com/a/xw32bey

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what you have set to what environment variable. You can't just put it all in the PATH variable.

Comment: I edited my original post with exactly what I ran in Powershell, and everything seemed to register without any errors, but still no luck unfortunately it still complains about "stdio.h: no include path set". I couldn't find the equivalent path for the "ATLMFC" directories you had listed, but added the 2019 equivalent of everything else. Edit: It also didn't seem to like the %PATH% line at the end so I removed that also.

Comment: My answer now provides the proper PowerShell syntax. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate you sticking with me on this and offering all these suggestions. I gave it a shot and Powershell didn't complain so I think it worked. Unfortunately I still get the error if I try compiling my hello.c program. As I mentioned, I don't know if maybe I should try finding the equivalent folder to the "ATLMFC" directory that is included in the first line of the INCLUDE and LIB parts. It's crazy that Windows makes this such a PITA to set up a C compiler, but thank goodness Windows 10 comes preinstalled with Candy Crush. :p

Comment: You may not have the ``ATLMFC`` folder because that's an optional install component with Visual Studio. What error are you getting? What edition/version of VS do you have installed?

Comment: The error I get is still "hello.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set" when I try compiling hello.c . I have the latest version of "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" which seems to be everything I need because I am able to get hello.c to compile using the "Developer console" that was installed with the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019". If you look at my original post I edited it with the directories on my computer and you can see how they vary slightly from the ones you provided (2019 folder vs 2017, different version number, "BuildTools" folder as part of the directory)

Comment: What version of Windows 10 SDK do you have installed?  What components did you select when installing the build tools? It probably came with ``10.0.19041.0`` rather than 10.0.17763.0. Make sure you have ``Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64`` and ``Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041``.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bmNlW0G  Here is a screenshot of my Visual Studio installer with the options checked. I'm pretty sure I have all the necessary pieces because the developer console works fine, I just can't seem to get the environment variables set up so it will work in a regular Powershell terminal.

Comment: Thanks for posting the edit with the 2019 commands. I tried those as well and replaced Enterprise with BuildTools where appropriate, but still getting that same error nagging me about stdio.h and "no include path set". Windows definitely didn't make this into a trivial exercise but I'm still determined to get it to work out of principal. Do you know if there is some way to confirm that these commands are doing what they are supposed to? I'm assuming they are working because Powershell doesn't yell at me when I enter them, but I see no noticeable difference when I check environment variables

Comment: After running the commands, if you type ``$env:INCLUDE`` into PowerShell do you see the values you set? You need "Machine-scope" permissions to set environment variables, but you should be errors if you try it and you don't have those.

Comment: I tried that command and it does nothing for me, no error, no text, the prompt in PowerShell just goes to the next line with no noticeable effect.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to let you know that i was reading a little about PowerShell environment variables and read something that gave me an idea, something about how they only apply to a certain session. I decided to use the commands you provided and leave PowerShell open after entering the commands, navigate to my hello.c file, and compile with cl. It worked! So apparently my problem was I kept closing PowerShell thinking i made permanent setting changes, but the environment variable changes only seem to apply to each individual PowerShell session. I'm really close now, thanks for everything!

Comment: I added a new answer to highlight how I got everything to work correctly, thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to use the developer prompt that comes with Visual Studio, as it sets all the environemental variables needed by the tools.  However, if you insist to do everything by hand, here is what I needed to do.

Opening a command prompt on my windows system and typing `cl` I get `cl` is not recognized as an internal or external command.  The issue here is that `cl.exe` is not on my path.  I can modify the path environmental variable so that the shell can find `cl.exe`.  On my system this is accomplished by doing

```
>set PATH="C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x64";%PATH%
```

which will add the path to `cl` to my PATH.  Note that this only works on the terminal that I am working in.  Once this works, you can set it through the environmental variables so it is persisted and available in all command prompts.

Once, `cl` is in my path I can attempt to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I am greeted with C1034: stdio.h no include path set.  This means that although the compiler has a built-in set of directories that it looks for include files, it can't find stdio.h.  The solution is that I need to tell it where to look.

Now on my system I can find it at "C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.190410\ucrt".  (Paths will be specific to my installation, you will need to find each file on your system).

Now I can tell the compiler where to find that file by using the /I (include search path) option [1].  Executing the following command

```
cl /I"C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt hello.c
```

Gives an error "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vcruntime.h'.  Another search of my hard-drive reveals that file to be at "C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include", and executing the following command

```
cl /I"C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"/I"C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" hello.c
```

Expanding the above command a bit to just do a compilation we can use the following

```
cl /c /I"C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"/I"C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" hello.c /Fo hello.o
```

To produce the object file `hello.o`.

Now on to linking.  The Microsoft linker is called LINK[2] and starting with

```
LINK hello.o /OUT:hello.exe
```

Gives an error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'.  Well this is progress, I gotten through the compilation phase and into the link phase, I only need to tell the compiler where to find the library.

Yet another search of my hard drive shows the library to be at
"C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib\x64", and running the following command,

```
LINK hello.o /LIBPATH:"C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib\x64" /OUT:hello.exe
```

Gives the error LNK1104: cannot open file "kernel32.lib", which I found at "C:\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"
I also had to add "C:\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64", to resolve libucrt.lib".  The following command

```
LINK hello.o /LIBPATH:"C:\VS2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" /OUT:hello.exe
```

Finally produce the output file hello.exe, which can as expected from a command prompt.

Remember that the above was for a simple hello-world style application.  As your program gets bigger, the various paths you will need to specify will get larger as well.  You may want to look into using `nmake` and using makefiles to manage you build.

[1] you can use "cl /?" to see all command line options available with the Microsoft compiler.

[2] you can use "LINK /?" to see all command line options available with the Microsoft linker.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I might mess around with this a bit and see if I can get a good result, although I hope I don't have to type those long commands each and every time and there is some way to set up the environment variables so it just works. I wanted to be able to simply type "cl hello.c" in PowerShell to compile my program, just like it works in the developer console. I find it so hard to believe that Windows made that impossible to do and am stubbornly seeking a way to make this work. I currently have it set up like you mentioned in the first few steps with cl in the path

Comment: Thanks again for contributing, take a look at my newest answer for how I got this to work exactly as described in my original post if you are at all interested.